# Auto excute SQL query after a fixed time in ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, sql-server-2008

I'm the new here. 
I've a problem like this: I create a Register page in ASP.NET (C#) which allow to guest can register an account at my site. All user must active their account before using my website, if after 15 minutes, user doesn't active account by mail => delete that user from database, my problem is how to do it automatically?

Comment: does it have to be exactly 15 minutes?  What about running some sort of job  every minute or so which cleans out the invalid registrations (those that haven't completed registration in the allotted time).  Fifteen minutes seems to short, though.  Email isn't real-time.

Comment: @JayC I'll check your link and feedback soon, anyway thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than using a timer to remove a user, I would use a more conventional approach of having an expiration time for the user (or perhaps their password). That is, when they first register, assign an expiration for 15 minutes after the present time (e.g. in a column `ExpirationDate` in the user table). In your authentication process, the logic should validate that the user's ID has not expired.

The problem with using a timer is that many things can go wrong. For example, if your application restarts, any active timers will be lost. It's very brittle. It's also kind of using a hammer to kill a fly. It's not necessary to ensure that someone's user record is removed immediately from the database after 15 minutes. It's only necessary to make sure they can't authenticate after that time. So make the design match the business purpose in the easiest possible way. If you really want to delete records (rather than, say, give them a chance to try again after resetting a password or something) then you can do this with some external maintenance process.

Comment: Thank dude! I understand what you say but my question just like an example, so many things can do if my problem solved, like a payment system at website which allow booked ticket online, after 15 minutes if you don't complete the payment (Paypal...) => your ticket will be delete. So on :)

Comment: I think the approach would be the same. You set an expiration in the ticket record. The next time it is accessed, part of the logic to validate is just check the expiration time. It's not important if it's a ticket or a user, you just have logic that determines if it's valid at the time it is accessed. There are many potential pitfalls with a timer and for a business use like this I see absolutely no reason to not just use logic and validate the record the next time it's accessed, and use offline maintenance to clear old old stuff periodically. You get no guarantees with a timer.

Comment: Thank dude, you're save my time. Very simple solution :)